# How to Map a Table to an Object Attribute?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a device with many identical sensors, so I need to mapping as much Entities Attributes as needed, instead of designing a table to each sensor.

How can I do that in Spring Boot?

Like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Devide {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Table(name = "sensor")
    private Sensor sensor1; // This is my conceptual problem


    @Table(name = "sensor")
    private Sensor sensor2; // This is my conceptual problem
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Isn't this a one to many relation ?  Please refer : https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: Yeah it's @ManyToOne, but how can I make this reference adding my FK in device and not in Sensor (I want Sensor to be generic and not only to one type of device). Is that possible?

Comment: Create ManyToMany relation b/w Device and Sensor and store relationship in third table Device_Sensor table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your one Device can have many sensors and one Sensor can be part of may devices, you have to create ManyToMany relation between Sensors and Devices. You can refer the following mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Device")
public class Device { 
    // ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Device_Sensor", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Device_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Sensor_id") }
    )
    Set<Sensor> Sensors = new HashSet<>();

    // standard constructor/getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Sensor")
public class Sensor {    
    // ...  

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Sensors")
    private Set<Device> Devices = new HashSet<>();

    // standard constructors/getters/setters   
}
```

Device_Sensor will act as a link between other two tables.